# How to parse the data in JSONKit with following format

Tags: iphone, objective-c, json, jsonkit

I have following data and i want to print the list of items with following structure.

Let me know how can i do that.

I can't get the data using the following syntax.

```
/* Data to Row Json from URL*/
NSString *MyRowJson = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:url
                                               encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil]; 

/* Copy data to Items from MyRowJson*/
NSDictionary *items = [MyRowJson objectFromJSONStringWithParseOptions:true];

/*get the deals data*/
NSMutableArray *ResponseData = [items objectForKey:@"deals"];

/*Get the count and based on this loop through the objects.*/    
NSLog(@"deals data count is %d",[ResponseData count]);
```

Here i got exception while printing the count.

Following is the structure of my data.

```
{
    "meta": {
        "code": 200
    }, 
    "response": {
        "deals": [
            {
                "id": 32373, 
                "date_added": "2011-01-13 12:12:50", 
                "end_date": "2011-01-14 10:00:00", 
                "active": 1, 
                "discount": {
                    "raw": 71, 
                    "formatted": "71%"
                }, 
                "price": {
                    "raw": "85.00", 
                    "formatted": "$85"
                }, 
                "value": {
                    "raw": "300.00", 
                    "formatted": "$300"
                }, 
                "title": "$85 For $300 Babyface Facial At Park Avenue MedSpa", 
                "yahoo_title": "71% off Babyface Facial", 
                "url": "http://yahoo.com/aff/click/?deal=AvwTADtE&key=F374EFbM", 
                "yahoo_url": "http://yahoo.com/new-york/livingsocial/85-for-300-babyface-facial-at-park-avenue-medspa/", 
                "mobile_url": "http://m.yahoo.com/new-york/livingsocial/85-for-300-babyface-facial-at-park-avenue-medspa/",
                "images": {
                    "image_big": "http://d22nv2k05ynu7x.cloudfront.net/deal_images/deal/85-for-300-babyface-facial-at-park-avenue-medspa-1294920769_display_image.jpg", 
                    "image_small": "http://d22nv2k05ynu7x.cloudfront.net/deal_images/deal/85-for-300-babyface-facial-at-park-avenue-medspa-1294920769_small_image.jpg"
                }, 
                "division": {
                    "slug": "new-york", 
                    "name": "New York", 
                    "active": 1, 
                    "time_zone_diff": -4, 
                    "lat": "40.7142690000000000", 
                    "lon": "-74.0059730000000000", 
                    "url": "http://yahoo.com/new-york/"
                }, 
                "tags": [
                    {
                        "name": "Facial", 
                        "slug": "facial", 
                        "url": "http://yahoo.com/new-york/deals/facial/"
                    }, 
                    {
                        "name": "Spa", 
                        "slug": "spa", 
                        "url": "http://yahoo.com/new-york/deals/spa/"
                    }
                ], 
                "business": {
                    "name": "Park Avenue MedSpa", 
                    "url": "", 
                    "locations": [
                        {
                            "address": "565 Park Ave", 
                           "locality": "New York",
                            "phone": "212-593-8821", 
                            "lat": null, 
                            "lon": null,
                            "state": NY,
                            "zip_code": "11211"
                        }
                    ]
                }, 
                "source": {
                    "name": "LivingSocial", 
                    "slug": "livingsocial", 
                    "paid": 0, 
                    "url": "http://yahoo.com/new-york/livingsocial"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: The JSON you posted isn't valid, check it for your self http://jsonlint.com. the problem is `"state": NY` the NY needs to be quoted `"state": "NY"`

Comment: Cosider it as updated and let me know how to move ahead as the this is snippet from actual data and the data is huge so i was not able to do paste here and this might be a type... please let me know. thtanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your are pasring the data correctly and you grab the deals from the top most node, but it is under the response node:

```
NSString *jsonData = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:url
                                               encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil]; 
NSError *error = nil;
NSDictionary *items = [jsonData JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:&error];

if (!items) {
   NSLog(@"Could not parse json:%@", error);
   return;
} 
/*get the deals data*/
NSDictionary  *response = [items objectForKey:@"response"];
NSArray *dealsArray = [response objectForKey:@"deals"];

/*Get the count and based on this loop through the objects.*/    
NSLog(@"deals data count is %d",[dealsArray count]);
```

Also object returned fro the JSON are inmutable, thus you can't just assign them to mutable objects.
You will need to use the `copyMutable` methode of the inmutable type to get the mutable type.
Do keep in mind that `copyMutable` need to released in non ARC projects.

Comment: Thanks for the super quick answer :) Though after breaking the bricks i meet with mountain.. How can i list down the internal properties of every section withing the deals segment. Please help in this. How to loop thought the data and put informations from their segments

Comment: I want to print business name.. i Drilled down to get business array with four elements and now want the name.                           NSArray *BusinessArray = [[dealsArray objectAtIndex:i]objectForKey:@"business"];  SOME CODE TO PRINT NAME